# Event Receiver which tries to create a Prefix will throw Security Exception

Tags: event-receivers, runwithelevatedprivileges, managed-path

I'm trying to use an Event Receiver on a List to create a Managed Path with Wildcard-inclusion in the parent WebApplication.
I tried to handle it with the following code (reduced to show the idea)

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
  () =>
  {
    using (var site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
    {
      var semester = new Semester(properties.ListItem);

      var webApplication = site.WebApplication;
      webApplication.Prefixes.Add(semester.UrlPart, SPPrefixType.WildcardInclusion);
      webApplication.Update(true);
    }
  });
```

If the code comes to Prefixes. And it will throw a SecurityException. The SharepointWebSite-Account is far away from least privilege at the moment (DB-Sysadmin, Local Admin, Farm Admin), but it refuses to perform my task.

I just tried to accomplish my Task with powershell logged on as the user in question - and it works - so the user privileges seem not to be the Problem.

For clearification: it's an asynchronous on ItemAdded Event-Receiver.

I found something in the logs, but as i said from Powershell it works with that user:

> 08/24/2012 13:46:16.80    w3wp.exe (0x13EC)
>     0x12C8  SharePoint Foundation           Topology
>     7f7y    High        Adding a new WildcardInclusion site prefix with the
>   path SoSe to the web application
>   MiscWebApp.   efa9c69b-9634-90de-f417-1b3bf5bf9325
>
> 08/24/2012 13:46:16.80    w3wp.exe (0x13EC)
>     0x12C8  SharePoint Foundation           Topology
>     8dyu    High        The SPPersistedObject, SPWebApplication
>   Name=MiscWebApp, could not be updated because the current user is not
>   a Farm Administrator. efa9c69b-9634-90de-f417-1b3bf5bf9325

Can anybody help?

Comment: If the user performing the list operation has sufficient right have you then tried to remove the RunWithElevatedPrivileges? This cause the code to run as AppPool account which hopefully isn't farm admin

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it this way and let me know if it fixes the issue:

```
var site = SPContext.Current.Site;
var currentWebApplication = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
  () =>
  {
    using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
    {
      var semester = new Semester(properties.ListItem);
      var webApplication = elevatedSite.WebApplication;
      webApplication.Prefixes.Add(semester.UrlPart, SPPrefixType.WildcardInclusion);
      webApplication.Update(true);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Besides that SPContext.Current is null in this EventReceiver (it's an asynchronous one), this is just what my code does ...

Answer (score 0):

First thing comes to mind is have you put your dll in the gac?

also look at this as its similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588675/sharepoint-event-receiver-not-working

**EDIT**

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges( 
  () => 
  { 
    using (var site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId)) 
    { 
      var semester = new Semester(properties.ListItem); 

      var webApplication = site.WebApplication; 

      webApplication.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

      webApplication.Prefixes.Add(semester.UrlPart, SPPrefixType.WildcardInclusion); 
      webApplication.Update(true); 

      webApplication.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    } 
  });
```

Iv just added AllowUnsafeUpdates when your updating to see if it makes a difference!

hope it helps :)

Comment: I struggeled with that for some time, but yes it is in GAC.
I connected the VS Debugger and the code is called, but runs into the security exception.

Comment: is there any way you can post the full error? do you have eventViewer or use uls http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463595.aspx just so i could give you a more specific answer

Comment: I added the logs to the original post.

Comment: I dont know if this would make any difference to you but you can try my edit!

Comment: I tried to, but the Problem here is, that webApplication is of Type SPApplication, which has no AllowUnsafeUpdates Property. As i see it in the Moment i have the Chance to do a _real_ impersonation (which i don't like, since i have to store the Password or allow Delegation) or i use an external Management Service, which handles my Task.

Comment: DO NOT USE ALLOWUNSAFE UPDATES! That is not its intended purpose and will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the Application Pool Identity for the content web application is not the same as the App Pool Identity for the Central Administration web application.

I would suggest moving the list to the Central Administration site collection. That site collection is just like any other. :)